# Custom color & tooltip for a single bar in Highcharts histogram

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to plot time-series data using Highcharts histogram & would like to have some way to highlight the bar that contains the latest datapoint (it will be the last element in the array) and also have a custom tooltip for the same.

So let's say I am plotting average daily temperatures for a city over a 1 year period -- how would I highlight the bar that contains the latest temperature & also provide a tooltip that indicates the same.

Lets say, in [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/histogram/) Highcharts example the last `3` in the `data` array is the latest temperature & I would like to highlight, as well as provide a custom tooltip for the bar with that value.

Something similar has been discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114797/highcharts-customize-tooltip-for-a-single-point) but it doesn't talk about highlighting the relevant bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the last point in `load` event and add a flag to distinguish it in the tooltip's formatter function:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var histogramSeries = this.series[0],
                    lastPoint = histogramSeries.points[histogramSeries.points.length - 1];

                lastPoint.update({
                    color: 'red'
                });
                lastPoint.isLast = true;
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.point.isLast) {
                return '<b>Last point result: </b> ' + this.y;
            }

            return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';

        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cefy419v/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Hi ppotaczek. I was looking over the example you posted & I realized that the bin being highlighted contains only a single value which is 4.4. What I want highlighted is the bin that includes the last element in the `data` array which happens to be 3. So the tallest bar would have to be highlighted. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think the array is getting sorted so the last point becomes 4.4 (which happens to be the largest element in the array). So.. I was wondering if I sort the array before I pass it to highcharts for plotting & also provide the exact index of the element I want highlighted (or even the element itself) would that make things easier? I tried changing `lastPoint = histogramSeries.points[histogramSeries.points.length - 1];` to `lastPoint = histogramSeries.points[57];` which is the index position of the first occurrence of the element `3` but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @truthseeker99, Yes, you are right. You can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0oam1pes/